# How to save axios response to a variable and update the state in react js?

Tags: reactjs, axios

### DataInsertSelect.jsx

```
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import Data from './Data'

class DataInsertSelect extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            datam: ""
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const axios = require('axios');
        // Make a request for a user with a given ID
        axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=5')
        .then( function (response) {
            // handle success
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
        })
        .then(function () {
            // always executed
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div className="col-sm-6 offset-sm-5">
                        {this.state.datam.map(joke=> (
                            <Data key={joke.id} title={joke.title} />
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm-10 offset-sm-2"><br/>
                    <form class="form-inline" action=" " method="post" >
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="email">FIRSTNAME:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="data1"
                                   class="form-control" id="email" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="pwd">LASTNAME:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="data2"
                                   class="form-control" id="pwd" />
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Submit</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default DataInsertSelect;
```

### Data.jsx

```
import React from 'react'

class Data extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <h3>{this.props.title}</h3>
        );
    }
}

export default Data;
```

Using `console.log(response);` outputs the 5 row data but I want to store the axios response to a variable and update the state and it needs to be displayed in the application.

Here also I am facing the error:

> TypeError: this.state.datam.map is not a function.

I tried a lot but could not fix it. I am an absolute begginer at React and axios.

I hope this is clear . Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The error :`TypeError: this.state.datam.map is not a function` you are getting because your `this.state.datam` is an empty string `""`, as declared in `Constructor`. And `map` is function available for `Arrays` and not `string`.

FIX: in `constructor`, instead use: `this.state={ datam : [] }`

2. To save the axios response into your state,do something like this:

```
axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos?_limit=5')
      .then((response)=> {
        console.log(response);
        this.setState({datam:response.data});     
      })
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now it shows TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined. 
  how to rectify this?

Comment: code updated.   `function(response)` will create its own context and hence converted it into `()=>{}`

Answer (score 0):

This example could help you

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Axios from 'axios';
export default class example extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
        users :[]        
    }
}
 componentDidMount(){
     Axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/')
.then(function (response) {
  this.setState({
    users: response.data,
});
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
})
 };

    render() {
        return (
            {
                 { users.lenght >0 ? (
           
            <tbody>
                 <tr>
                   <td>{this.state.id}</td>
                   <td>{this.state.username}</td>
                   <td>{this.state.email}</td>
                 </tr>
            </tbody>

       ):(
         <h1>No data available!</h1>
       )
         
      }
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.